# How to rewrite a FP library Ramda.js function called 'pathSatisfies' in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

> [Read here about the function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathSatisfies)

> - External library can not be used to do this.
> - Cannot use any Node-specific APIs like `fs`, `util` etc.

#### Parameters

`pathSatisfies` accepts 3 params.

1. a predicate function
2. an array containing the name of the keys (aka. the path)

- It will always contain elements of string type.

3. **Any** object for which the path may be satisfied.

**Is there a way to implement this in pure JS?**

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Also why don't you just use ramda if you're ok with external libraries?

Comment: it can't be used

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you an idea how you can start thinking about the problem:

What is the trivial case?

- When the path is empty -> just call the predicate function on the object

What is the reduction step if the path is not empty to get closer to the trivial case?

- Use object[path[0]] as the new object and use the rest of the path as the new path.

Which leads to a straightforward recursive function:

```js
function pathSatisfies(fn, path, obj) {
    if (path.length === 0) {
        return fn(obj);
    }
    return pathSatisfies(fn, path.slice(1), obj[path[0]]);
}
```

This does not check for any cases like path is not in the object etc. It is also trivial to convert to iteration without using `.slice()` to get better performance.